# Google maps, delete the clicked marker

Tags: javascript, marker

I create some marker and add some event to them. 
How can I make the marker that has been clicked can not be clicked again?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. Please read the help section on how to ask good questions, specifically [https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and [https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: In short tho: use an array to contain your markers, an id to identify your marker's position in the array when you create it, so that when you click on it you can `splice` (delete) the marker from the array.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Thank you @Andy, I got u. That's the idea I need and I solve the problem. Plus, Because I do not want to change the order of the array, i used delete. :)